# what is block confirmation

Tags: blockchain, block, validation

[image: a random block that the confirmation section section id circled] in the details of a bitcoin block there's a section called block confirmation (which is different than transaction confirmation), first i thought it was the number of the blocks that are created after this block but there is a lot of blocks that has one confirmation with a great number of blocks after them, i would appreciate it if you can tell me how does that work?

Comment: Your initial thoughts look correct based on what I see in https://www.blockchain.com/explorer for last few blocks. Can you share examples for blocks with 1 confirmation?

Comment: https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/block/bitcoin/718082

Comment: it's not just one confirmation they are diffrent

Comment: check this one out,this was on the fifth page and still has 2 confirmations.

Comment: Sorry just realised we are looking at different explorers. Not sure why is it 1 for so many blocks in coinmarketcap block explorer. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Not sure how you got 1 confirmation for "so many blocks". When I check either of the two explorers mentioned above I get confirmations that are consistent with the number of blocks mined since.

Comment: that actually helps thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question. That detail seems to be specific to the block explorer you are using; can't say what it means as it's not official terminology and I couldn't find anything similar when I just looked on three different popular block explorer websites.

To answer your question more directly, block confirmation is something that most likely has little to no importance or relevance to the mining process.

Comment: yes, apparently that's a bug in the explorer i was checking or maybe the blockchain was forked at that point that the number of the blocks after that specific block is one.